# How can I reduce the number of parameters?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm implementing a recursive version of max increasing subsequence but I think that I'm using too parameters.

Strategy:

- list of elements (integers)
- list of lengths (max length of subsequence)
- list of references (element that I should go to find the next element in the subsequence)

Implementation:

```
def search(i,j,elements,references,leng,temp):
    if i == len(elements):
        return references,leng

    if j < 0:
        return search(i+1,i,elements,references,leng,0)

    if temp < leng[j] and elements[i] > elements[j]:

        leng[i] = leng[j] + 1
        references[i] = j
        temp = leng[j]

    return search(i,j-1,elements,references,leng,temp)
```

First call:

```
leng = [1]*len(elements)
references = [-1]*len(elements)

references,leng = search(0,0,elements,references,leng,0)
```

It would be very helpful if you can explain me how I can reduce the number of parameters.

Thanks.

Comment: Put the parameters in a list. Now you have only one parameter :P

Comment: Make sure you reproduce your indentation accurately when posting Python code. Otherwise you are introducing new errors into the code.

Comment: @ForceBru Passing mutable objects might cause other level of issues though.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it this way:

```
def search(**parameters):
    # unpack the dictonary
    a = parameters['a']

dictonary = {'a': 0}
foo = search(dictonary)
```

You can now pass a dictionary with parameters and assign them in the function